# When I try to run Angry Birds, I get a resolution error. How do I fix this?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, angry-birds

I want to run Angry Birds but it shows me this error:

```
  the maximum resolution is 1024*1024
```

My current resolution is 1024 * 768.  What is the problem?

Comment: my current resolution is 1024 * 768

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved it by updating my VGA card driver.